# Many-to-Many Relationship and Avoiding Double Counting

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having issue with many to many relationship in SQL. It is causing double counting in the numbers.
Below is the table structures.

```
Table: Invoice  
   Columns: InvoiceID (PK),
            TaskID    (FK),
            Invoice Rate

Table: Task  
   Columns: TaskID (PK),
            ProjectID    (FK),
            ...

Table: Project  
   Columns: ProjectID (PK),
            ...

Table: ProjectCustomer (this is the bridge table)  
   Columns: ProjectID (PK),
            CustomerID (PK)
            ...

Table: Customer  
   Columns: CustomerID (PK),
            ...
```

The many to many here is that 1 project can have multiple customers and 1 customer can have multiple projects.
As you see above, there is already a bridge table where ProjectID and CustomerID form the composite PK of ProjectCustomer table.

I'd like to create a query to give me result of invoice rate per project, customer (and time period).
However, for projects which have multiple customers, the total numbers are not right.

What is the best way to tackle this so that the numbers are correct?
Should I apportion the numbers depending on the number of customers per project, e.g. if 2 customers for a project, then the number is divided by 2?

Also, is there a better way to structure the tables?

Comment: Please show us your existing query, along with the current and desired results.

Comment: Please share sample data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the total InvoiceRate for each project and get the customernames separately using CROSS APPLY or derived table, to avoid doubling the count. I would suggest you to keep customer names list, instead of repeating customers for each row and dividing the Invoicerate as you will not get the right numbers in some cases, where you are dividing.

1. First decide the driving table and the result you want. Here, driving table is Project, task and Invoice. So, you get the data you want.
2. Then other columns should be derived from the driving table information. Here, the information is: Customer names.

I have provided pseudo code. I have not tested it. Hope you get the idea.

```sql
SELECT p.ProjectId, cust.CustomerNames, SUM(t.InvoiceRate) As TotalCost 
FROM Project AS p
JOIN Task AS t
ON t.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
GROUP BY p.ProjectId
CROSS APPLY
(SELECT STRING_AGG(CustomerName,',') As CustomerNames
FROM ProjectCustomer AS pc
JOIN Customer AS c
ON c.CustomerId = pc.CustomerId
WHERE pc.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
) AS cust
```

or

```sql
SELECT p.ProjectId, 
(SELECT STRING_AGG(CustomerName,',') 
FROM ProjectCustomer AS pc
JOIN Customer AS c
ON c.CustomerId = pc.CustomerId
WHERE pc.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
) As CustomerNames, SUM(t.InvoiceRate) As TotalCost 
FROM Project AS p
JOIN Task AS t
ON t.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
GROUP BY p.ProjectId
```